# How to send sms/text to any number using email without knowing carrier/service provider

Tags: mobile, twilio, sms, att, sms-gateway

To send sms/text via email to a verizon number you can email PHONENUMBER@vtext.com. To send it to att number you can email PHONENUMBER@txt.att.net . This requires knowing which mobile operator the phone number belongs. Is there any way to send sms/text to a number without knowing the operator the number belongs to.

If there is some such third party services, how do they implement this service. Do they email all the operators and hope that it reaches through atleast one of those emails OR do they use any sms gateway?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Using the [Twilio SMS API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api) you can send messages to numbers all around the world. This is not using the often undocumented and potentially flaky phone number email scheme. Instead Twilio has deals and connections to carriers and other partners that we use to route messages around the world to the destination hand sets. We call this [the Super Network and you can read more about it here](https://www.twilio.com/super-network).

Comment: Thanks @philnash how does Twilio figure out which network to send the text to based on the phone number?

Comment: With complex decision making software that we have written that lets us analyse and choose between our delivery partners. All of that is proprietary software but this [white paper on our infrastructure](https://ahoy.twilio.com/twilio-intelligent-infrastructure) might shed a bit more light on things.